# 90s sci-fi tv show on small channel with three women leads that jump levels?

Tags: story-identification

90s sci fi tv show with 3 women leads. It was on something like channel 5 (Los Angeles) or similar small station. I remember these ladies jumping in and out of levels while fighting bad guys. That is all I can remember. Driving me crazy....

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you sure there are no other details you remember?

Comment: It sounds a bit like *Charlie's Angels* to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is something of a long shot, but I think you are describing [Cleopatra 2525](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0206476/?ref_=nv_sr_2). It had 3 female leads, and no lack of jumping.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't sound like a long-shot to me; this was my immediate choice. They all jumped between floors of some sort of CGI silo on clearly irrelevant ropes several times per episode.

Comment: This was it! That is awesome! I am complete. Thank you.