Tv show - women look for men in deep hole in the future
Women look for men in deep hole in the future.
Title song was "scarcely a man was left alive".
They float down in a big hole to lower levels.

Welcome to SciFi.SE! Any extra details you could [edit] in? When did you watch this? Was it in colour or black-and-white? Was it a movie or more episodic in nature? What do they float on (if anything)?

Did they battle a specific type of enemy (mutants, robots, etc)?  How many women were there in the primary cast?

"scarcely a man was left alive" is a bible misquote, but I can't find any song with that lyric in it.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

I'm going to take a wild swing at this one and suggest a short-lived TV show from the year 2000.  Memories fade after more than two decades, but based on what little data has been provided I'm going to suggest Cleopatra 2525.
The main cast was composed of three women.  The theme music was an altered version of the popular In The Year 2525 (the show's intro is on YouTube).  The lyrics are similar to the phrase provided in the question ("In the year 2525, If man is still alive, If woman can survive").
The show's characters travel through underground "shafts" built by the "shaft builders" to travel from one underground level to another.  Here's an outtake from a good review from IGN:

For those of you that have wondered, "If Ed Wood had made a TV show,
what would it have been like?" your curiosity can now be sated. Just
like the work of the beloved yet mis-guided Wood, Cleopatra 2525 is a
show that will contort your face; from a look of disgust to puzzlement
to, finally, amusement. This thing is so out there, so cheesy, that
you can't help but find it entertaining. The syndicated show debuted
in 2000, along with Bruce Campbell's Jack of All Trades, but only
lasted for a season and a half before it was cancelled. The handful of
fans out there will probably snap this boxed set up no matter what,
but for everyone else out there that is considering it, you have to
ask yourself one question: Do you like camp?
In the year 2001 Cleopatra (Jennifer Sky) goes in for a boob-job. She
wakes up in the year 2525 to find that human-kind lives in a concrete
jungle beneath the earth. She buddies up with two equally
scantily-clad women, Hel (a pre-Firefly Gina Torres), and Sarge
(Victoria Pratt). The three of them then spend episode after episode
running around kicking ass and blowing stuff up, all the while dodging
mutants and big CG robots. Yes, it really does sound like a series a
pair of fourteen year-old boys would have made up after staying up all
night to play Xbox and watch soft-core porn. Throw in a ridiculous
theme-song, "In the yearrr 2525, they're women with the will to
surviiiive," and you've got a show that, while you know it should
never have been made, still somehow entertains.
I went into this thing not expecting to come out impressed. I'm not.
However, I didn't expect to find myself enjoying the show either. Yet,
on the lowest level of brain function possible, I did. I'm not exactly
sure what it is. Was it the fact that these women would jump down a
massive elevator shaft each week to predictable adventures? Was it the
campy style that makes Hercules and Xena look high-class? Was it the
nearly-nude females shooting lasers from their gauntlets in slow
motion? Probably all three.





If confirmed, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128151/90s-sci-fi-tv-show-on-small-channel-with-three-women-leads-that-jump-levels/128156#128156

But did she ever get her boob job?
